# CSS float: right not working

Tags: css-float

On [this page](http://walks.doig.com.au/category/london/), I have:

```
<div class="featured-image">
  <img width="150" height="150" src="http://walks.doig.com.au/files/2014/04/london-attractions-150x150.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="walk-text">
  <h2><a href="http://walks.doig.com.au/london/london-2-from-the-british-museum-to-the-london-eye/">London #2 from the British Museum to the London Eye</a></h2>
  <div class="entry-summary">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut non leo dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed egestas sagittis dolor eget faucibus. Aenean vestibulum sagittis purus eu venenatis. Fusce odio ligula, volutpat sed orci eget, interdum bibendum elit. Donec tempor vitae lorem sed eleifend. Donec rhoncus velit at ullamcorper egestas. Vestibulum [&hellip;]</p>
  </div>
  <!-- .entry-summary --> 
</div>
```

and

```
.featured-image {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 14px;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
.walk-text {
  float: right;
}
```

Why isn't div.walk-text displayed on the same horizontal line as div.featured-image?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you try set some width?

This code example can help to you

```
.walk-text {
  float: right;
  width: 70%;
}
.featured-image {
  width: 27%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 14px;
  margin-right: 1rem;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks.  I forgot the element needed a width.

Answer (score 1):

```
.walk-text h2 p{
    float:right;
}
```

I think this link is helpful: 
 [demojsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2sZYq/)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by adding width to .walk-text:

```
.walk-text {
    float: right;
    width: 460px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

delete the float:left from the featured-image class. instead add the following

```
img
{
    float:left;
}

.featured-image {
 margin-right: 14px;
 margin-right: 1rem;
 }
```